# Multiplying specific elements in a matrix

Tags: java, matrix, multiplication

I have two matrices

```
A = {{1,2,3},
     {4,5,6},
     {7,8,9}};

B = {{1,2,3,10},
     {4,5,6,11},
     {7,8,9,12},
     {1,2,3,13}};
```

I want to multiply them in the following manner. 
elements {5,6},{8,9} from matrix A multiplied with {1,2},{4,5} (elements from B). I know I can multiply individual indexes but How can I loop through them?

I am not sure how to approach this problem. If someone can just give me a hint, it would be a great help.

I am not looking for an answer. A simple logic on how I can do this using loops would be enough.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried pesudo code but I am unable to get it around my head as of now

Comment: Are you intending to do matrix multiplication?

Comment: Sort of. My goal is to start from the corner and keep going. So basically start from top left corner and proceed until I reach the bottom right corner.

Comment: @Constantin that multiplies the entire matrix. I want to start from last 4 elements of A multiplied with first 4 elements of B and so on.

Comment: 5x6x8x9  x  1x2x4x5 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83697/discussion-between-mani-and-constantin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are not coming to chat. Sorry but I must run.
Here is a possible solution to your problem:

```
    int A[][] = new int[][]{{1,2,3},
                            {4,5,6},
                            {7,8,9}};
    int B[][] = new int[][]{{1,2,3,10},
                            {4,5,6,11},
                            {7,8,9,12},
                            {1,2,3,13}};

    System.out.println("====================");
    int number = 1;
    for(int rowIndex = A.length - 2; rowIndex < A.length; rowIndex++) {
        for(int colIndex = A[0].length - 2; colIndex < A[0].length; colIndex++) {
            number *= A[rowIndex][colIndex];
            System.out.print(A[rowIndex][colIndex] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.println("====================");     
    for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 2; rowIndex++) {
        for(int colIndex = 0; colIndex < 2; colIndex++) {
            number *= B[rowIndex][colIndex];
            System.out.print(B[rowIndex][colIndex] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.println("====================");
    System.out.print("ANSWER IS: " + number);
```

Output:

```
====================
5   6   
8   9   
====================
1   2   
4   5   
====================
ANSWER IS: 86400
```

Comment: There was a bug in my previous answer ... A[0].length is the column's length, not the rows length (which is A.length)   code is now fixed ... sorry about that

Comment: How did you get 86400?

Comment: I multiply all the numbers as you wanted. 5x6x8x9    x    1x2x4x5